# An Error Related to data: id in erc1155 smartcontract

Tags: solidity, polygon, erc-1155, frontend, moralis

We successfully deployed/integrated our erc1155 smart-contract through the website:

Frontend[The Website link](https://177dq8.csb.app/)

> Unfortunately, the only problem we have now is that when we mint the
> smart-contract for the second time, the ID does not change. It is
> still 1[ Data id: 1 ].

Couldn't find where exactly this id error

Here's our erc1155 smart-contract:

as we use always  polygon network for deployment:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/common/ERC2981.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract AmpToken is ERC1155, ERC2981, ReentrancyGuard {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;

    enum PaymentStatus{PENDINGPAYMENT, SENT}

    //EVENTS//
    event AmpCreated(
        uint256 indexed id,
        address creator,
        address owner,
        string name,
        uint256 price,
        uint256 _amount
    );

    struct Amp {
        uint256 id;
        address payable creator;
        uint256 price;
        uint256 amount;
        string name;
        bool valid;
   }

    struct Payment{
        uint256 id;
        address learner;
        PaymentStatus _state;
        
    }

    address payable public owner;
    uint256 lillupPrice = 0.000033 ether;

    //change to private before going live
    mapping(uint256 => Amp) public idToAmp;
    mapping(uint256 => Payment) public idToPay;
    mapping(uint256 => bool) private soldOut;
    mapping(address => bool) public creators;
    mapping(address => bool) public apprvLearner;
    mapping(address => bool) public whitelist;
    mapping (address => uint256) internal balances;

    uint256 public nextCreatorsId;
    uint256 public nextLearnerId;
    uint256 public nextPaymentId;
    uint public totalAmp;
    

    constructor() ERC1155("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeigb7tqhulo5zciqshuzvofz3pv7kozrs57fgjo53jz5n4qkl66qzu/Amp.json") {
        // set royalty of all NFTs to 8%
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        _setDefaultRoyalty(owner, 800);
    }

    //OWNER ONLY//
    function approveCreators(address _creators) onlyOwner public {
        //Contract owner approves new admin addresses - Complete
        //require check that the address being added doesnt already exist - Complete
        require(creators[_creators] != true, "Already Creator");
        creators[_creators] = true;
        nextCreatorsId++;
    }

    function withdraw() external onlyOwner nonReentrant {
        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(success, "Transfer failed.");
    }
    //loading the token balance
    function BalanceOf(address _creators) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_creators];
    }
    
    //CREATIRS ONLY//
    /* MINT AMP NFT*/
    function createAmp(
        string memory _name,
        uint256 _id,
        uint256 _price,
        uint256 _amount
    ) public payable virtual  returns (uint256) {
    //  Do you want them to give their own ID or go in order of nextAmpId?
    //  This would require our frontend dev to make sure nextAmpID is a set field on frontend.
    //  require(idToAmp[_id].id == nextAmpId, "Please select the next Amp ID");
    //  require(idToAmp[_id].valid == false, "This ID is already taken");
    //  require(_price > 0 * 10^18, "Price must be at least 1 MATIC");
    //  8% Royalties should go to owner
        _setDefaultRoyalty(owner, 800);
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        idToAmp[_id].creator = payable(msg.sender);
        idToAmp[_id].name = _name;
        idToAmp[_id].price = _price;
        idToAmp[_id].amount = _amount;
        idToAmp[_id].valid = true;
        
        _mint(msg.sender, _id, _amount, "");

        totalAmp += _amount;

        return newTokenId;

    //  createCourseItem(_id, _price, _amount, _name);        
    }
    
    //need to have royalties sent to Owner once Amp tokens are sent to Learner
    function sendAmp(
        address _to,
        uint256 _id,
        uint256 _amount
    ) public  nonReentrant {

        idToPay[_id] = Payment(
            idToPay[_id].id = nextPaymentId,
            _to,
            idToPay[_id]._state = PaymentStatus.PENDINGPAYMENT
        );
        nextPaymentId++;


        
        //require(msg.value == listingPrice, "Price must be equal to listing price");
        idToAmp[_id] = Amp(
            _id,
            payable(msg.sender),
            _amount,
            idToAmp[_id].price,
            idToAmp[_id].name,
            idToAmp[_id].valid
        );
        
        


        //set enum status to pending payment
        
        _safeTransferFrom(_msgSender(), _to, _id, _amount, "");

    }

     function sendPayment(uint _id) public payable onlyLearner {
        //Needs to have learner send payment to creator if amount is correct
        //function needs to be called in the sendAMP function above.
        Payment storage payment = idToPay[_id];
        require(msg.sender == payment.learner, "Please connect the correct wallet address");
        require(idToPay[_id]._state == PaymentStatus.PENDINGPAYMENT, "Payment Not Active");   
        
    }


    //Triggers payment for item if customer sends correct amount for item.
    /*function triggerPayment(uint _itemIndex) public payable {
        require(items[_itemIndex]._itemPrice == msg.value, "Only full payments accepted");
        require(items[_itemIndex]._state == SupplyChainState.Created, "Item is further in the chain");
        
        items[_itemIndex]._state = SupplyChainState.Paid;
        
        emit SupplyChainStep(_itemIndex, uint(items[_itemIndex]._state), address(items[_itemIndex]._item));
    }
    */
    
    function setLearner(address _learner) public {
        require(
           creators[_learner] != true,
            "Already a creator. This address cannot be student"
        );
        apprvLearner[_learner] = true;
        nextLearnerId++;
    }
    
    //students added to whitelist don't pay when buying course
    function setWhiteList(address _whitelist) public onlyCreators {
        whitelist[_whitelist] = true;
        
    }

    /* Creates the sale of a marketplace item */
    /* Transfers ownership of the item, as well as funds between parties */
    function createMarketSale(uint256 _id, uint256 _amount)
        public
        payable
        onlyLearner
    {
        address creator = idToAmp[_id].creator;
        uint256 price = idToAmp[_id].price;
        uint256 tokenId = idToAmp[_id].id;
        require(idToAmp[_id].amount >= 1, "Course Sold Out");
        require(_amount == 1, "Amount too high, Select 1 token");
        idToAmp[_id].creator = payable(address(0));
        //Need to Add If statment for whitelist users. If Admin does not want to charge a student there address should be added to the whitelist
        if (whitelist[_msgSender()] == true) {
            _safeTransferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId, _amount, "");
            payable(creator).transfer(msg.value);
            idToAmp[_id].amount = idToAmp[_id].amount - 1;
            
        } else {
            require(msg.value == price, "Please submit the asking price");
            _safeTransferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId, _amount, "");
            payable(creator).transfer(msg.value);
            idToAmp[_id].amount = idToAmp[_id].amount - 1;
            
        }
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override(ERC1155, ERC2981)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    function onERC1155Received(
        address,
        address,
        uint256,
        uint256,
        bytes memory
    ) public virtual returns (bytes4) {
        return this.onERC1155Received.selector;
    }

    function onERC1155BatchReceived(
        address,
        address,
        uint256[] memory,
        uint256[] memory,
        bytes memory
    ) public virtual returns (bytes4) {
        return this.onERC1155BatchReceived.selector;
    }

    /*
     // Updates the listing price of the contract Has no Function at the moment
    function updateListingPrice(uint _listingPrice) public payable onlyOwner {
      listingPrice = _listingPrice;
    }

     // Returns the listing price of the contract. Has No function at the moment
    function getListingPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
      return listingPrice;
    }
    */

    //MODIFIERS//
    //OnlyAdmins can use functions that utilize this modifier

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner == msg.sender , "Only Owner");
        _;
    }
    modifier onlyCreators() {
        require(creators[_msgSender()] == true, "Only Creators");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyLearner() {
        require(
            apprvLearner[_msgSender()] == true,
            "Please register as a Student"
        );
        _;
    }
}
```

[image: Here]

Need Some Support!

Thank You..

Comment: Do you get this issue when you are trying to mint amp NFT? (Or mint more NFT's at once?)

Comment: @Sky  thank you for responding || ah! well  when I'm trying to mint for a second/more times
**In simple: when I mint for the first time i got id "1"; but for the next/second it wasn't changed (still the id was "1"**

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I have gone through the code you posted, and there are some things that seem off in `createAmp()`

For example, the function requires `_id` as an imput. From what I see this you need to add id on your own for each imput. That is rather unusual, even more so as there is `_tokenIds` counter that one would assume would be used for getting new `_id`

```
    function createAmp(
        string memory _name,
        uint256 _id,
        uint256 _price,
        uint256 _amount
    ) public payable virtual  returns (uint256) {
    //  Do you want them to give their own ID or go in order of nextAmpId?
    //  This would require our frontend dev to make sure nextAmpID is a set field on frontend.
    //  require(idToAmp[_id].id == nextAmpId, "Please select the next Amp ID");
    //  require(idToAmp[_id].valid == false, "This ID is already taken");
    //  require(_price > 0 * 10^18, "Price must be at least 1 MATIC");
    //  8% Royalties should go to owner
        _setDefaultRoyalty(owner, 800);
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        idToAmp[_id].creator = payable(msg.sender);
        idToAmp[_id].name = _name;
        idToAmp[_id].price = _price;
        idToAmp[_id].amount = _amount;
        idToAmp[_id].valid = true;
        
        _mint(msg.sender, _id, _amount, "");

        totalAmp += _amount;

        return newTokenId;

    //  createCourseItem(_id, _price, _amount, _name);        
    }
```

Here I modified it so that `_id` is automatic:

```
function createAmp(
    string memory _name,
    uint256 _price,
    uint256 _amount
) public payable virtual  returns (uint256) {

    _setDefaultRoyalty(owner, 800);
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
    idToAmp[newTokenId].creator = payable(msg.sender);
    idToAmp[newTokenId].name = _name;
    idToAmp[newTokenId].price = _price;
    idToAmp[newTokenId].amount = _amount;
    idToAmp[newTokenId].valid = true;
    
    _mint(msg.sender, newTokenId, _amount, "");

    totalAmp += _amount;

    return newTokenId;       
}
```

BONUS CODE:

For some reason your Amp NFT structure's packaging is not optimized, (meaning you pay more gas for minting NFT than you should). So I wrote optimized one.

```
struct Amp {
    uint256 id;
    uint256 price;
    uint256 amount;
    address payable creator;
    bool valid;
    string name;
```

}

PS: You could also save A LOT if you would use `uint32` or `uint64` instead of `uint256`. Not to mention you could use `bytes` instead of `string` for the Amp NFT name.

Comment: thank you so much means a lot; I'll do the rest and run it and thanks again for bonus code too